# Blocking constructor in Go

Tags: go

Assume I have a type `Connection`, which represents say a TCP connection. Establishing a connection is a blocking operation. I see two ways to design its interface, and my question is which of them is more idiomatic in Go:

1. `func NewConnection(...) (*Connection, error)` blocks and returns an established connection.

   - Pros: Can't have invalid `Connection`s hanging around. Any `Connection` in memory is an established, valid connection.
   - Cons: A blocking constructor might be surprising.
2. `func NewConnection(...) Connection` immediately returns a fresh connection, and we need to call a blocking `func (c *Connection) Establish() error` to actually establish the connection.

   - Pros: Nonblocking constructor seems more "normal" to me.
   - Cons: People might forget to call `Establish`. This is trivial in this case, but in case where the type is complicated and we need to do a lot of configuration on it (and might even need to call things in certain order), this leaves the programmer much greater opportunity to screw up.

Comment: in the standard api there is no such things like a New of net connection. instead, there is a Dial function, that returns an established connection (https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial), or an error. it seems to me you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @mh-cbon The connection type is just an example, my question is about any type that needs blocking initiation in general.

Comment: Set the expectations for #1 by naming the function “Dial”.

Comment: i see. Follow the std api, don t use surprising constructor, prefer package methods with clear meaning. I believe there is no constructor that panics in the std api, or returns an error, but i m not 100% sure of that, at least, for my own i would not.

Comment: @mh-cbon "or returns an error" --- https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open
It totally is okay to return an error from a constructor, from the software design perspective they don't have any special properties from other functions.

Comment: "A blocking constructor might be surprising." No, a non-blocking constructor would be surprising - what would it do, return a channel and then return the newly-created instance on the channel async? Though from context I'm guessing you don't actually mean just "blocking", you mean something like "a constructor that blocks indefinitely".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments suggest, there's nothing wrong with a blocking constructor, but the naming of the function should reflect the fact that it may block. The documentation should, too.

In the standard library, if you want to create a new socket and connect to some server you can do it in a single call: `net.Dial`

```
func Dial(network, address string) (Conn, error)
```

It's a blocking operation that returns a new `Conn`.

So it's idiomatic to do this in Go, you should just name it right. I agree with your intuition that #2 is less great for usability.

Comment: One may also add a context to make it cancellable.

Comment: @zerkms: true. In the `net` package `DialContext` does that

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After reading some code in the stdlib, I'm gradually realizing that there really isn't a concept of "constructor" in Go. It's just a creator function.